# How to make Angular read another time app.component.html

Tags: angular, frontend

For a school project I'm currently using Angular. I have a full website with login, register, home  and other pages. 
I have a mat-toolbar on the top that allows users to return to home page.

This toolbar is declared in app.component.html. Problem is that this html file is read once so I can't put a variable in there so toolbar shows in some pages.

Do you have some recommendations ? How do you usually do this ? I know I can define it in the concerned html files but it isn't very elegant...

Thx =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every component which is not lazy loaded works based on app.component, so when you put your toolbar there, it is obvious to see that on every page. In general we are solving that problem by lazy load component which are visible when user login.

I will create some such a code for you which is not lazy loaded and I will edit it as lazy loaded. Then, you can compare them and change your code to solve this problem.

**Without Lazy Loading**

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        AppComponent,
        ProfileComponent
    ],

    imports: [ 
       BrowserModule,
       AppRoutingModule...
    ],

    providers: [
    ],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '' , component: HomeComponent },
  {path: 'register' , component: RegisterComponent },
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', children: [ // here is after login, so have authguard. I didnt implement it there.
     {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
        ...

]}
]
```

By using that method you will face to face with toolbar at every page.

**With Lazy Loading**

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        AppComponent,
    ],

    imports: [ 
           BrowserModule,
           AppRoutingModule...
    ],

    providers: [
    ],

})
```

> You must delete everything which is not required for you before login. You must add them into YourModule.

*app.routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '' , component: HomeComponent },
  {path: 'register' , component: RegisterComponent },
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: "pathOfYourModule>#NameOfYourModule"}
]
```

*your.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ // your components which app will use after login.
       DashboardComponent, DashboardAppComponent, ProfileComponent
    ],

    imports: [ // modules which app will use after login
       CommonModule, YourRouingModule
    ],

    providers: [ // services which app will use after login
    ],

})
export class YourModule {}
```

*your.routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardAppComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: DashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'profile',
                component: ProfileComponent
            }
        ],
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class YourRoutingModule { }
```

Last of all, you must delete everything you wrote from app.component.ts and html files. 
app.component.html must only contains `<routing-outlet></routing-outlet>`

Finally, right now you can declare your toolbar at DashboardAppComponent.